# Is there an improvement for my sql query?

Tags: php, mysql

is there any way to remove the MAX with something else, maybe the `ASC LIMIT 1` to decrease database throttling? My query gets the maximum id and adds 1 to it.

This is my query:

```
$query = 'SELECT MAX(ID) +1 as maxidpost  
          FROM wp_posts';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo 'p='. $row['maxidpost'];
}
mysql_close();
```

Comment: If you are using it for inserting, have you tried `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the `ID` field?

Comment: Do you have database throttling ?

Comment: He's doesn't seem to be using it for inserting, given he is printing it (see the code)

Comment: Yes I have database throttling...

Comment: @Matthieu: obviously... The code is a demo of the query, not how it will be ultimately used. @Mairy: How do you intend to use the ID+1 value? If you don't plan on inserting with that value, then by all means your query is fine, otherwise there is a better way.

Comment: @Mairy Do you have an index on the ID column ?

Comment: You could eliminate the `while()` loop, since your query would only ever return one row anyways.

Comment: How can I eliminate it? This is the only way I can show the result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the database tell you about your query?  If id is indexed then

```
mysql> explain select max(id) + 1 from times;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Select tables optimized away |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.18 sec)

mysql> explain select id from times order by id ASC limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | times | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So by having asc limit 1 is faster right? But, does the 0.18 sec are considered to be a big difference in time?

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. adding `limit 1` isn't going to give any noticeable performance improvements.

This shouldn't cause any kind of issues, are you having problems with this particular query?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL `MAX()` function will automatically look for just one result. There's no need of `LIMIT` it in any way. If you want to improve that query try setting `ID` as index.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ID + as maxidpost FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;`
or If the table have Auto_increment ID
`SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'wp_posts';`
There should be a field called Auto_increment which should be exactly MAX(ID) + 1;